# Don't know which build tools my current project uses?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, build-tools

I am working a continued project of react/redux. But, Don't know which build tools it uses? 
Whether it is webpack, Gulp, Grunt, etc..?

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "some-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.1.3",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.1",
    "react-firebase": "^2.2.7-4",
    "react-firebase-file-uploader": "^2.4.1",
    "react-notification-system-redux": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should google such things as this varies from dev to dev and such questions are not entertained on StackOverflow network.

Comment: I would check `package.json` file first.

Comment: Can find exact answer's @Mr.Alien

Comment: Speak to whoever worked on it before, look for a readme, ask your teammates. These are things that need to be part of your knowledge transfer when you hopped on the team :) You can get a rough idea from a package.json

Comment: @KaleemElahi You won't find until you try some. Also read what Muthu suggested... It depends on what node packages are used, is it using WebPack to build or Gulp

Comment: I checked that too & added to Que. @Mr.Alien

Comment: @KaleemElahi Refer `react-scripts` package, you'll get the relevant info there.

Comment: Yes, I referred and it, The project is using create-react-app & it hides all webpack configuration, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Create React App - Zero Configuration?**
>
> If you’re working with React, you’re probably familiar with the
>   create-react-app. It’s an official command line interface for building
>   React applications with ZERO Configuration.

**ZERO Configuration? How is it possible?**

create-react-app hides all the webpack configuration into a package react-scripts. With create-react-app, I can enjoy all the configuration created by Facebook without any effort and I don't need to configure myself.

But... you are not POSSIBLE to change the default configurations provided by Facebook create-react-app. Facebook provided 2 options to allow you to change the default configurations...

Refer : https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-scripts#zero-configuration-how-is-it-possible